# file logging with serilog in IIS

Tags: iis, logging, serilog

I need to log some funcionality in my web API published in IIS so I have this in startup.cs

```
fileLog = @"c:\inetpub\wwwroot\planificadorwebapi\planificadorLog.json";

  Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .ReadFrom.Configuration(Configuration)
    .WriteTo.File(new JsonFormatter(), fileLog, shared: true)
    .CreateLogger();
```

I try to creat the file in the folder of the application but this file is never created. I make requests that log information but the file does not exist

When I start the application in Visual Studio the file is created and this works perfectly

Any idea please?

Regards

Comment: Check your IIS application pool Indentity user if has access permission on your designated folder

Comment: also search "Serilog SelfLog" to ease diagnosing this (also Sysinternals Filemon can be useful in this space)

Comment: In my Application the identity is asigned to "ApplicationPoolIdentity" I don't know to which user this corresponds. IIS_IUSRS maybe?

Answer (score 1):

I did permission to write int the folder of the application to the account IIS_IUSRS and now the file is created well

Thanks